# Problem with FontAwesome font-weight when using fa-regular

Tags: angular, font-awesome

Chrome 115 and 117 (also in Edge)
fa-solid displays ok but regular display as square
[here how it look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2I8kH.png)
when trying to play with font-weight in the DevTool its look like the browser cant display font-weight less than 600.
Help

I want to be able use all font-weights

Answer (score 0):

To change the line thickness of FontAwesome icons, you have to select the right font. This cannot be done via `font-weight`. In the free version you only have the solid icons. If you also need icons with thinner lines, the regular, light, thin, and duotone styles are available in the paid pro version.
See here: https://fontawesome.com/docs/web/dig-deeper/styles

Comment: Thanks for your response.
This happens in both the free and pro versions.

Comment: Can you share some CSS/Html how you use it? As I said, you should not use `font-weight` at all. If you want icons with thinner lines, use CSS class e.g. `fa-light` instead of `fa-solid`